# grep for 2 words in OR condition and next 10th line print

Tags: linux, unix, grep

Required your help

```
2016/03/31 07:00:00 ----- [200]  Number **123456789**  word **ACK**
.
.
10th Line
            **WAITING**

2016/03/31 07:00:00 ----- [200]  Number **123456789**  word **OUT**
.
.
10th Line
            **CLEAR**
```

I want to grep the number 123456789, and also the word ACK or OUT both (OR Condition); when both patterns are found, then print the 10th of line word "WAITING or CLEAR".

I tried

```
grep -ri "123456789" filepath | grep -ri "ACK\|OUT"
```

but this does not print the next 10th line of content.

Comment: does your `grep` support the `-A` option? (`man grep`). **but** `awk` is probably a better tool to solve this problem. Update your Q with your required output given those 2 "records".   Good luck.

Comment: `awk` is probably the primary tool for this problem. With `sed` you could find (`123..` and `ACK`) or (`123...` and `OUT`) and then the 10th line that follows, but not find `123...` and (`ACK` or `OUT`) at the same time.

Comment: Oh, upon closer inspection, my answer might be wrong. What do you mean by "the 10th of line word 'WAITING or CLEAR'" exactly?

Comment: Hi Benjamin, Thank

Comment: i find out this  grep -rA 10 "123456789" | grep -ri "ACK" --- Separately another grer for OUT...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This *beautiful* sed one-liner can do it:

```
sed -n '/123456789.*\(ACK\|OUT\)/{n;n;n;n;n;n;n;n;n;n;p}' infile
```

This assumes that on the matching line, the number comes before the `ACK` or `OUT`. Once a line matches that pattern, the command loads the next line 10 times with `n`, then prints the pattern space with `p`. All other lines are not printed because of the `-n` option.

For in input file that looks like

```
2016/03/31 07:00:00 ----- [200]  Number **123456789**  word **ACK**
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10th line after ACK
blah
blah
2016/03/31 07:00:00 ----- [200]  Number **123456789**  word **OUT**
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10th line after OUT
```

the result is

```
$ sed -n '/123456789.*\(ACK\|OUT\)/{n;n;n;n;n;n;n;n;n;n;p}' infile
10th line after ACK
10th line after OUT
```

To get this to run with BSD sed (as used in Mac OS), there has to be an extra `;` between the `p` and the closing brace.

Comment: *beauty*, as always, is in the eye of the beholder. Can't sed have an N modifier for `n` ie `10n`!?  ;-) . Good luck to all.

Comment: @shellter I fiddled around with `~`, which can skip lines, as in `1~10p`, which would print lines number 1, 11, 21 etc., but it sadly only takes line numbers as addresses :(

Comment: LOL, hey, had forgot about that one. ( and of course, I was only kidding about `10n` (but not a bad idea, maybe?). Good luck.

Comment: @shellter Not sure how active the sed development is these days! ;)

Comment: Thanks ... Ill try